# how stopped script while procces id exist? Solaris

Tags: bash, awk, while-loop, do-while

I want to stall the execution of my script until a process is closed (I have the PID stored in a variable).

```
#!/bin/bash

outputl=$( ps -ef | grep $var4 | awk '{print $2}' )  >> $logfile

while [ "ps -p $outputl" ]  > /dev/null;
do 
  sleep 1; 
done
echo "Stopped $instance" >> $logfile
//command...
```

It stays in the "while" and not continue whit script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
while [ "ps -p $output1" ]
```

does not execute the `ps` command. It simply tests whether the string `"ps -p $output1"` is not empty, and it obviously isn't. To test the output of a command, use `$()`:

```
while [ "$(ps -p "$output1")" ]
```

But since `ps` produces a header, this will always be true. The best way to test if a PID exists is to use the `kill` command with signal 0; this doesn't actually send a signal, it just tests whether it's possible to send a signal. I'm assuming this code is being run either by `root` or the userid running the application being checked. So you can write:

```
while kill -0 "$output1" 2>/dev/null
```

Also, your code for getting the PID into `$output1` is wrong. `ps -ef` will also include the `grep` command, which matches the name you're looking for, so you need to filter that out. Use:

```
output1=$(ps -ef | grep "$var4" | awk '!/grep/ { print $2 }')
```

Redirecting the output to `$logfile` is not necessary, since variable assignments don't print anything.

Many systems have a `pgrep` command, which can be used by itself to test if a process with a given name exists; if you have this, you can use it instead of reinventing the wheel (and if not, you should be able to install it).

Comment: That's not going to work, either.  That `ps` command might still produce a header line.  Try this: `while ps -p $output1 > /dev/null; do`

Comment: Thanks Barmar and Jack, your comments were very utils, Thanks.

Comment: If your system has `pgrep`, it's the right thing to use.

Comment: Given the right PID in `$outputl`, you could simply use `while ps -p "$outputl" >/dev/null; do sleep 1; done`.  The `kill -0 $outputl 2>/dev/null` probably also works, and arguably does less work (a single system call).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the PID then just `wait` for it to complete. Try:

```
outputl=$( ps -ef | awk -v v="$var4" '$0~v{print $2}' )
wait "$outputl"
echo "Stopped $instance" >> $logfile
```

then look for a better way to find the pid in the first line.